# Tuleap - Estimated Time Response

Tags: tuleap, time-estimation

Is it possible to calculate the time based response in Tuleap. What i mean is that when a task was submitted, Tuleap by default can capture the submitted on value (date and time), now i want to know whether Tuleap can set up the estimated time value by +2 or +3 hrs from the submitted on data. So that the end user will know this task has to be completed with in 2 or 3 hours. Estimate time value can be triggered based on some other input.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the smallest unit time available is day, so this does not seem to be feasable. Tuleap is more of a tracking tool (what happend) than a managing tool (what should happend).